# Regex to test if an input string contains a certain number of characters

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

So, I basically would like to test to see if a string contains a range of alphanumeric characters. It's to be used as a client-side validation and I don't want to prevent users from entering whatever they want. Best to give examples of what should/should not pass validation:

So to be specific, the expression I'm looking for is to test to make sure string contains anywhere from 3 to 10 alphanumeric characters. I'd like to plug into an ASP.NET client side validator.

NOTE: quotes not part of input (but could be!)

- "  f o o " should pass since there are 3 chars
- "f_0_0" should pass
- " fo " should not
- "F......o......o......b.....a......r" should pass

thx

Answer (score 1):

```
^([^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9][^a-zA-Z0-9]*){3,10}$
```

Allows for exactly 3-10 alphanumeric characters, each surrounded by an arbitrary number of non-alphanumeric characters.

(Untested, but it should conform to [the JScript subset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x.aspx) of the standard .net Regex syntax, as [required by the RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx). Unfortunately, the shorthands `\w` and `\W` cannot be used since they include the underscore as an alphanumeric character.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ASP.NET client-side validators, so I'm not sure if you *need* to do this in a regex, but potentially an easy solution is as follows:

1. Remove all non-alphanumeric characters (regex replace `[^0-9A-Za-z]` with nothing).
2. Check if string length is 3 or greater.